# OLOO vs. OO in reactjs front-end web dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I read Kyle's book, and I found it really informative.
But I am a little confused on the discussion in "You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes".

That series say that `Object Linking to Other Object` design pattern is cleaner and simpler then `object oriented` design pattern. I do agree with this.

But I notice that many react code snippet prefer using ES6 class keyword which represents `object oriented` code style.

Comment: Firstly, the whole "OLOO is better than classes" is just the author's opinion (although I think he makes his point well). And even if you agree with it, to use React you have to use ES6 classes, because that's how the React API is designed.

Comment: OLOO is *an* object-oriented pattern as well.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you don't have to teach programmers that you introduce to your project to OOP pattern as it is by far the most popular one and people are used to it. Teaching someone consumes time and money - two things that business value the most.

Second thing would be that it is hard to prove that one programming paradigm is better than the other - especially if you can count on one hand implementations of OLOO when OOP has hundreds of thousands.

Just because something is better (I also agree with Kyle) doesn't mean it will be the most popular choice.